# Apply different CSS classes without using Vuetify's breakpoint service

Tags: css, vue.js, responsive-design, vuetify.js

Is there a way to apply different CSS classes to an element in a Vue/Vuetify app at different breakpoints (screen widths), e.g.

```
.exra-small {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.small-and-above {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

I know that I can do this using Vuetify's breakpoint service like so:

```
<div :class="$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly ? 'extra-small' : 'small-and-above'">
</div>
```

But I'd prefer not to use this because I find that style changes applied via the breakpoint service are not very smooth, compared to pure CSS solutions. Presumably this is because the former uses JavaScript, whereas the latter uses media queries.

Comment: why dont you try the same using computed

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. If you want to apply breakpoints through css, then... apply them through css. There's nothing preventing you from assigning a class and using media queries in css to style it differently for different breakpoints. On a different note: Keep in mind that the lag is a debounce function. Mobile devices usually don't suddenly grow, meaning you only have this issue while resizing the browser. See https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11101 for a workaround with vuetify.